# Sending email does not work

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to send an email after a user enter some contact data but it seems that the email does not get sent as expected.I do not work with php very often so I might have missed something.Here is my code:

```
function sendEmail($data){
      $to      = 'alexandru.nistor.89@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'From My Portfolio Website!';
      $message = $data[3]['value'];
      $headers = 'From: ' . $data[0]['value'] . " " . $data[1]['value'] . "\r\n" .
    ' Reply-To: '. $data[2]['value']  . "\r\n";

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Now before you ask the function gets called I have checked with the debugger and the data is added corectly to the variables the only problems is that the mail does not arive to the destination.Am I doing somethign wrong?

Comment: Any error while you run the code above?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and add a catch (`die`)

Comment: Checked your spam/junk folder?

Comment: I have added try catch is seems the code runs and no exceptions ar thrown an no the mails are not in the spam

Comment: ok I have changed the email adress to an yahoo emaila ddress and it seems it works.The gmail account was created only 3 days ago could this be the problem?

Comment: Check your mail logs to see if gmail is rejecting it outright, aka your server is blacklisted. Other than that either your message looks like spam, or gmail just doesn't like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what function `mail()` returns.
If returns `false` it means it's error in php. If it returns `true` it means it is accepted for delivery but not necesery will reach its destination. In this case it's more network related.

More info at docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have changed the email to a yahoo email and for that mail it works it is something related to the gmail email I think